# "Connection failed, activation of network failed" error

Tags: dual-boot, network-manager, connection

I keep getting the "Connection failed, activation of network failed" error pop up even if I am connected to the WiFi and have access to the internet. I am on dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04.

I took a look at the network manager logs and here is what I got:

```
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4288] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4306] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (4f23e5d8-103f-3fcc-adf5-18a056362def)
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4313] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4323] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4334] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4342] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135802.4414] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): dhclient started with pid 13688
Feb 02 14:30:02 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:05 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:12 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:23 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:36 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:43 21K-USER dhclient[13688]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u3c2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb0140b5b)
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <warn>  [1549135847.3719] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): request timed out
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135847.3720] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): state changed unknown -> timeout
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135847.4042] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13688
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135847.4042] dhcp4 (enp0s20f0u3c2): state changed timeout -> done
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135847.4046] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <warn>  [1549135847.4050] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb 02 14:30:47 21K-USER NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1549135847.4057] device (enp0s20f0u3c2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

EDIT1: after running the lshw -C network command:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 44:85:00:70:d2:8a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=172.31.123.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:e1000000-e1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 70:5a:0f:19:9c:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:128 memory:e1100000-e111ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3c2
       serial: e6:70:1c:12:20:17
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device link=yes multicast=yes
```

EDIT 2: running `cat /etc/network/interfaces` gives :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

running `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` gives:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

running `dkms status` after installing it does not output anything.

EDIT 3: As suggested by @heynnema
These are the current findings:

1- I have tried updating the BIOS. Problem still persists.

2- I have tried running `dpkg -l *CDC* | grep ii` and `pkg -l *cdc* | grep ii`. Unfortunately, no matches are found.

3- I have tried running `lsmod | grep cdc` and this is the output:

```
cdc_wdm                20480  1 qmi_wwan
cdc_ether              16384  0
usbnet                 45056  2 qmi_wwan,cdc_ether
```

Comment: One of us is confused. Your log appears to show a "Wired Connection 1" and a device of enp0s20f0u3c2... which sounds like an ethernet device. Is it wired or wireless that you're having trouble with? Do you have a log for wireless errors? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Oh, maybe you mean... I'm connected via wireless, but can't get my ethernet to connect? Your subject title may have thrown me off. Please describe how your ethernet cabling is connected, from computer to router. Also, edit your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is exactly why i've been hitting my head against the wall. I am connected via WiFi, and I am NOT trying to connect via ethernet. The error keeps showing up even though i'm not trying to establish any 'Wired connection'.  I edited my post, thanks again.

Comment: Do you have an ethernet cable plugged into your computer?

Comment: @heynnema no, not at all.

Comment: Why does it show you have 2 ethernet interfaces, and one of them DOES have a link?

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Using NetworkManager or Netplan?

Comment: @heynnema I honestly don't know. I guess you will have to take me for my word in this one. There are NO ethernet cables plugged to my computer. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, network manager.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dkms status`. Do you know what `CDC Ethernet Device` is?

Comment: @heynnema Edited. No, unfortunately, I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a second ethernet-like device, enp0s20f0u3c2, running with a "cdc_ether" driver from 2005. It's a "CDC Ethernet Device". The system thinks there's an active link to it, and that's were the bogus "Connection failed, activation of network failed" errors are coming from.

Either somebody installed some old driver software, or maybe there's something in your BIOS that's enabled some hardware that we don't know about. Check your motherboard specs.

Nothing in `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` gives us any clues. DKMS doesn't show us anything either.

1. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and issue a `sudo lshw -C network` command in `terminal` and see if it shows a enp0s20f0u3c2 (*it may have different numbers associated with it*) ethernet device. That will tell us if it's software related.
2. Review your BIOS settings, and check the manufacturer's web site for BIOS updates.
3. Review your software looking for something related to "CDC Ethernet". In `terminal` try `dpkg -l *CDC* | grep ii` or `dpkg -l *cdc* | grep ii`. Report back if you find anything.
4. `lsmod | grep cdc` and see if it finds a kernel module.

**Update #1:**

Step #4, above, showed us that there is in fact a `cdc_ether` kernel module installed. This may be due to a previous `USB to 4G` dongle, a `USB to Ethernet` dongle, a `TomTom` GPS device, or an internal 4G adapter.

Since we're not sure exactly which software install might have added this `cdc_ether` driver, and associated software, we'll try a safe way to fix this first...

Create a new blacklist file...

In `terminal`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc_ether.conf` # create the file

Add these two lines...

`blacklist cdc_ether`

`blacklist usbnet`

Save the file and reboot the computer.

Then do...

`sudo lshw -C network` # show us the current network devices

and confirm that the `enp0s20f0u3c2` ethernet device is no longer present. If it's still there, then do the following, but only if it's still there...

`sudo modprobe -r cdc_ether usbnet` # remove these kernel modules

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k "$(uname -r)"` # update the initramfs

reboot the computer and check the `lshw` command again.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Will try that and get back to you.

Comment: @Kamoukou status please

Comment: I am very sorry for taking a lot of time. I've only had time to try the 2, 3, 4. I will update my post shortly. I will try the first suggestion when I get home. Thank you for following up.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to uninstall the CDC driver to solve the problem ?

Comment: @Kamoukou ah, we found the little sucker! It makes me ask, did you ever have a `USB to Ethernet` adapter connected to your computer? After a few more questions, I'll put together a plan to remove the driver.

Comment: @Kamoukou did you ever have a `USB 4G Modem`, internal 4G, or a `TomTom` GPS device?

Comment: @Kamoukou see my Update #1 in my answer. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No I never had any one of the devices you have mentioned, ever. However, I do have a slot of internal 4g for my computer, although I have never used it. I have tried what you suggested, and blacklisting have worked for me. The ethernet device is no longer present. Thank you so much ! Is there anything else I should do ?

Comment: @Kamoukou if you ever decide to use the internal 4G, you'll have to remove the file that we added, for it to work.